azure open ai gpt-4o issue with image analysis and C#
I'm using bot framework sdk with C# to call Azure open AI model gpt-4o for image analysis. i receive following response or variance of it. however when i upload same exact image to azure open ai studio it's able to analyze it. also when i use python it's able to analyze it. what could be the issue with this c# code?
response i receive or variations of it:
"I'm currently unable to directly analyze images from files or URLs, but I can help guide you on how to describe what’s in the image or help you with other questions or tasks related to it! If you can describe the image, I can assist you better. Please provide some details or let me know how I can help!"
so is this particular piece correct?
string base64Image = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
// Prepare GPT-4 payload with Base64 image
ChatCompletionsOptions gpt4Options = new ChatCompletionsOptions()
{
    Messages =
    {
        new ChatMessage(ChatRole.System, @"You are an AI assistant that helps people find information."),
        new ChatMessage(ChatRole.User, @"Here's an image for you to analyze."),
        //new ChatMessage(ChatRole.User, base64Image) // Add the base64 image as a user message
        new ChatMessage(ChatRole.User, $"{{\"type\": \"image_url\", \"image_url\": \"data:image/png;base64,{base64Image}\"}}") 
       // $"{{\"type\": \"image_url\", \"image_url\": {{\"url\": \"data:image/png;base64,{base64Image}\"}}}}")
    },
    // ... other options like Temperature, MaxTokens, etc.
};

complete code:
// Generated with EchoBot .NET Template version v4.22.0

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Schema;
using System;
using Azure;
using Azure.AI.OpenAI;
using System.IO; // Required for working with files
using System.Text; // Required for Base64 encoding
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace EchoBot.Bots
{
    public class EchoBot : ActivityHandler
    {
        static readonly HttpClient client2 = new HttpClient();
        protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Check if the activity contains any text
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(turnContext.Activity.Text))
            {
                var replyText = $"Echo: {turnContext.Activity.Text}";
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(replyText, replyText), cancellationToken);

                OpenAIClient client = new OpenAIClient(new Uri("https://mct-openai01.openai.azure.com/"),
                 new AzureKeyCredential("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"));

                Response<ChatCompletions> responseWithoutStream = await client.GetChatCompletionsAsync("mct-gpt4o-01",
                 new ChatCompletionsOptions()
                 {
                    Messages =
                    {
                        new ChatMessage(ChatRole.System, @"You are an AI assistant that helps people find information."),
                        new ChatMessage(ChatRole.User, @"You are an AI assistant that helps people find information."),
                     },
                     Temperature = (float)0.7,
                     MaxTokens = 800,
                     NucleusSamplingFactor = (float)0.95,
                     FrequencyPenalty = 0,
                     PresencePenalty = 0,
                 });
                ChatCompletions response = responseWithoutStream.Value;
                string completionText = response.Choices[0].Message.Content;
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(completionText, completionText), cancellationToken);
            }
            else if (turnContext.Activity.Attachments.Count > 0)
            {
                // User sent an attachment
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(" I see you sent one!"), cancellationToken);
                if (turnContext.Activity.Attachments.Count == 1 && turnContext.Activity.Attachments[0].ContentType.StartsWith("image/"))
                {
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(" starts with image"), cancellationToken);
                    // Only process the first attachment if it's an image
                    var attachment = turnContext.Activity.Attachments[0];
                    if (attachment.ContentType.Contains("image/"))
                    {
                        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(" contains"), cancellationToken);
                        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
                        var attachmentUrl = attachment.ContentUrl;
                        try
                        {
                            var attachmentResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(attachmentUrl, cancellationToken);
                            if (attachmentResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                            {
                                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                                {
                                    await attachmentResponse.Content.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                                    byte[] imageBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                                    // Convert image to Base64 string
                                    string base64Image = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
                                    // Prepare GPT-4 payload with Base64 image
                                    ChatCompletionsOptions gpt4Options = new ChatCompletionsOptions()
                                    {
                                        Messages =
                                        {
                                            new ChatMessage(ChatRole.System, @"You are an AI assistant that helps people find information."),
                                            new ChatMessage(ChatRole.User, @"Here's an image for you to analyze."),
                                            //new ChatMessage(ChatRole.User, base64Image) // Add the base64 image as a user message
                                            new ChatMessage(ChatRole.User, $"{{\"type\": \"image_url\", \"image_url\": \"data:image/png;base64,{base64Image}\"}}") 
                                            // $"{{\"type\": \"image_url\", \"image_url\": {{\"url\": \"data:image/png;base64,{base64Image}\"}}}}")
                                        },
                                        // ... other options like Temperature, MaxTokens, etc.
                                    };
                                    // Send the request with the image data
                                    OpenAIClient client = new OpenAIClient(new Uri("https://mct-openai01.openai.azure.com/"),
                                    new AzureKeyCredential("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"));
                                    Response<ChatCompletions> gpt4Response = await client.GetChatCompletionsAsync("mct-gpt4o-01", gpt4Options);
                                    ChatCompletions response = gpt4Response.Value;
                                    string completionText = response.Choices[0].Message.Content;
                                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(completionText, completionText), cancellationToken);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // Handle download failure (e.g., inform user)
                                //await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("else statment"), cancellationToken);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            // Handle exceptions during download (e.g., logging)
                            //await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("catch statment"), cancellationToken);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var welcomeText = "Hello and welcome!";
            foreach (var member in membersAdded)
            {
                if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
                {
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(welcomeText, welcomeText), cancellationToken);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

did anyone face same issue with c# ?

did you find a way? facing this issue as well...

The GPT-4o model introduces a new rapid audio input response that -- according to OpenAI -- is similar to a human, with an average response timer increase account

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
